# WiFi interface doesn't come up

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, kernel, iwlwifi

All of sudden, my builtin Wifi interface on the laptop (HP Pavilion dv7, running Ubuntu 12.04, kernel 3.2.0-64-generic)  won't come up.

```
# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:25:c2:d9:fb:8c  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
# iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
```

"dmesg" command shows

```
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Here are some of the kernel modules

```
# lsmod | grep iw
iwlwifi               381794  0 
mac80211              543880  1 iwlwifi
cfg80211              210370  2 iwlwifi,mac80211
compat                 13447  7 iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211,bnep,rfcomm,bluetooth,usbnet
```

I have the "network-manager" running, the icon is in the system tray, but it doesn't show  any wireless network even though it's only a few feet away from the WiFi router (my cell phone can talk to the WiFi router fine).

command "iwlist wlan0 scan" show a list ESSIDs (including my WiFi router).

I have tried the following but it didn't help.
    sudo ifdown wlan0
    sudo ifup wlan0

Rebooting the laptop didn't help either.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Part of dmesg

```
[ 5534.540251] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[ 5544.897099] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 5544.907411] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5544.907414] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 5544.907416] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5544.907418] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5544.907419] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5544.907421] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5544.907423] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5544.910517] iwlwifi: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[ 5544.910519] iwlwifi: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
[ 5544.910605] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 17 (level, low) -> IRQ 17
[ 5544.910651] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
[ 5544.910692] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: pci_resource_len = 0x00002000
[ 5544.910694] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: pci_resource_base = ffffc90012614000
[ 5544.910695] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: HW Revision ID = 0x67
[ 5544.910856] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: irq 53 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 5544.915028] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: loaded firmware version 41.28.5.1 build 33926
[ 5544.915490] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[ 5544.915500] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[ 5544.915508] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[ 5544.915515] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TESTMODE disabled
[ 5544.915523] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_P2P enabled
[ 5544.915531] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 BGN, REV=0x84
[ 5544.915733] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[ 5544.926407] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x557, CALIB=0x6
[ 5544.926411] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Device SKU: 0x150
[ 5544.926414] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Valid Tx ant: 0x1, Valid Rx ant: 0x3
[ 5544.926433] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Tunable channels: 13 802.11bg, 0 802.11a channels
[ 5544.926586] Registered led device: phy0-led
[ 5544.926621] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[ 5544.926785] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try editing `/etc/network/interfaces`:

`auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wireless-essid [ESSID]
        wpa-psk password` `

If it's a problem with your network manager this should help.

More info: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse